# Unable to load flat file using SSIS with filename as variable

Tags: ssis, etl

I am working with a text file that I am trying load into a database where the filename is dynamic. I have an SQL task that queries a database for the "from" path. Then I have a Process task that uses PowerShell to look for the file of interest using a search string in the folder name I obtained in the previous task. The result from the Powershell command is stored into variable "source_filename". Then I use TRIM(@User::source_filename) as the ConnectionString expression for my Flat File Connection Manager.

However, when I execute the package (in SSDT) the Data Flow Task fails at the Flat File Source with the following error (note the space at the end of the error):

*[Flat_Source [17]] Error: Cannot open the datafile "...\xxx_xxx_201802_20180316.txt ".*

This verifies that the filename is returning the right file name in the "source_filename" variable, but it fails. To test the file load tasks, I hard-code the filename as the source_filename default value, I disable the PS command that revalues the source_filename variable during run-time, and then re-run the package. The file loads just fine and I receive the following progress note (notice no space at the end of the file name):

*[Flat_Source [17]] Information: The processing of file "...\xxx_xxx_201802_20180316.txt" has started.*

I have also coded my Powershell command in a way that will not return a space at the end of the file name. I have also used TRIM() specifically in the Flat File Source ConnectionString expression. Does anyone have any advice on why SSIS is appending a space to my connection string when I am defensively programming against it, and how to fix it?

I originally started out with a ForEachLoop container, but that was when the problem originally started. I then switched to the Powershell command to have more precise control on the filename output. However, the TRIM() in the connection string expression should be solving any spaces issue.

Thanks!

Comment: The ForEachLoop container is definitely a tried and tested method for this type of task. I suggest you troubleshoot that further

Comment: I assume your are using a UNC, and all of these tests have been run in the same environment (i.e. consistently in SSDT or SQL Agent)

Comment: I would use the for loop and loop through the folder path.  When assigning the variable are you setting the variouabe = value?  or appending the valie to the varable?  Maybe the variable has a space in it before you populate it and it is keeping the space for some reason?

Comment: Thanks for the responses... The loop container returns the same bad result. Even using trim() after I get the variable back from the loop container does not prevent SSIS processing the file with the space and failing.

Comment: That is very strange and also at odds with every example given of the for loop container. I suggest you start with a basic functioning for each file example and work towards whatever you have now.